# iOS 14 User permission required to be displayed in which of my usecases?

Tags: ios, ads, ios14, idfa

Do I need to ask permission from iOS 14 users for displaying personalized ads or even for accessing only the IDFA that is not used for personalized ads or by data brokers anywhere..?

I need to keep tracking user demographic data which is done by Analytics SDK by accessing the IDFA.

Comment: If you don't request and obtain tracking authorisation you will receive 0's for the IDFA once apple introduces the tracking limitations.  You will also get 0s for the IDFA if the user has opted out of tracking.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your reply. Yes, I read this somewhere else. I'm trying to ensure my app gets accepted in the review. Will Apple accept the app if I don't ask permission since I'll be getting only 0s for IDFA value?

Comment: I don't know. I suspect that if your app includes code to access the IDFA and you don't have tracking authorisation request then you risk a rejection.